# How to hide Robots.txt in search engine results?

Tags: asp.net, iis, seo, robots.txt, search-engine-bots

I don't want to see *Robots.txt* in result list of search. I'm working on an **asp.net** project.

I found some failed solutions, one of them like below:

> - Using "X-Robots-Tag" in header.

But I want to hide a txt file so there is no "header" part in it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capitalization is important to most popular search engines, including Google ([source](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)). Change your file name from `Robots.txt` to `robots.txt`. If you name it correctly, most popular search engines (Bing, Yahoo, Google, etc.) will not index it. No extra effort on your part.

[Here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/nl/yahoo/ysearch/slurp/slurp-02.html) is Yahoo's crawler help that describes case-sensitivity.

[Here](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) is the standard that describes common courtesy for crawlers with regards to robots.txt. It is explicitly stated that empty robots.txt files are ignored completely, and it is common sense that they are not indexed. Otherwise, we would see billions of robots.txt search results in Google.

Comment: Can you give me a source for your first sentence ("Most popular search engines (Bing, Yahoo, Google, etc.) look for robots.txt at the root of your hierarchy. They do not index it. No extra effort on your part.").

Because i must prove it to my boss :) .

Comment: @Hayzum Your comment was posted two minutes post-edit.

Comment: @Hayzum Tell your boss that nothing can stop a web crawler from ignoring common courtesy and indexing ALL of your files. Web crawlers do not have to follow these rules if they choose not to. But why would your boss care about the availability of your robots.txt file? There should be no sensitive information there.

Answer (score 0):

A txt file sent via http has a header(containing type:text/plain) just take request and send txt with your own headers.